# SuggestBox in GWT-Not able to select content with mouse in Internet explorer

Tags: gwt

I have a suggestion box in GWT; I am not able to select the contents of suggest box with mouse in internet explorer.

Code is as below:

```
    oracle = new MultiWordSuggestOracle();
    suggestBox = new SuggestBox(oracle);
    suggestBox.setAutoSelectEnabled(true);

    suggestBox.setWidth("100%");
    suggestBox.getElement().setId("find_text");

    suggestBox.getTextBox().addBlurHandler(new BlurHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onBlur(BlurEvent event) {
            Log.debug("inside blurrrrrrrrr:"+event);
            suggestBox.setFocus(true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you explain more what you're expecting and what you're getting? The word "select" has lots of meanings. Can you describe exactly what you mean by it.

Comment: suppose i enter data such as "alca" in suggestbox and if i try to copy the content with mouse, its not happening on IE, other browsers i'm able to copy and select the content what i have entered in suggestbox

Comment: Can you do it with a regular TextBox?

Comment: Even a textbox is not allowing to select its content in mouse on internet explorer